# Domain of $f(g(x)),g(f(x)),f(f(x))$ in composite function

Tags: functions

> If $\displaystyle f(x)=4/x$ and $g(x)=4x+1$. Then domain of $f(g(x)),g(f(x)),g(g(x)),f(f(x))$ are

What i try: $$f(g(x))=\frac{4}{g(x)}=\frac{4}{4x+1}$$

So domain is $\displaystyle x\in\mathbb{R}-\{\frac{1}{4}\}$

$$g(f(x))=4f(x)+1=\frac{16}{x}+1$$

So domain is $x\in\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$

$$f(f(x))=\frac{4}{f(x)}=x$$

So domain is $x\in\mathbb{R}$

But domain not matched with answer.

Please tell me where i am missing

Thanks

Comment: But $f(0)$ is not defined, so u still need to exclude 0

Comment: The domain of $f(f(x))$ is the range of $f(x)$. But to get range of $f(x)$ you need domain of $f(x)$ which is $x\in R-\{0\}$. Hence, $f(x)$ will not take input as $x=0$ and $f(f(x))$ will not get input corresponding to $x=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you have two functions $F$ and $G$, the "largest domain" to $G\circ F$ is
$$\{x \in \mbox{dom}(F) : F(x)\in\mbox{dom}(G)\} \ ,$$
which is simply $\mbox{dom}(F)\cap F^{-1}(\mbox{dom}(G))$.
In that way, we always have $\mbox{dom}(G\circ F) \subseteq \mbox{dom}(F)$.